# App will freeze and then the screen only shows the status bar. Any suggestions?

Tags: java, android, xml

The application freezes and the screen will become blank after I press the option represented by the upcoming xml(like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7qUo.jpg)

The same happens for another option in which the xml is pretty identical(the EditTexts reads strings in the other xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/interval1txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/interval2txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/interval1txt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor"
        tools:numeric="integer" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/interval2txt"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Generează"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="De la"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/interval1txt"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Până la"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rezultTXT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/interval2txt"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/interval2txt"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, the specific code for this xml is the following:

```
package com.example.elev.myapplication2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;
 import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;



public class intervalNumClass extends Activity{
EditText itxt1,itxt2;
int i1,i2,rez;
TextView rezr;
Button CautaRnd;
Random r=new Random();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.intervalnum_layout);

    itxt1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.interval1txt);
    itxt2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.interval2txt);
    CautaRnd=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    rezr=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.rezultTXT);

    do {
        itxt1.getText();
    }while(itxt1.length()<=0);
    i1=Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(itxt1));

    do {
       itxt2.getText();
    }while(itxt2.length()<=0);
    i2=Integer.valueOf(itxt2.getText().toString());


    CautaRnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            rez = i1 + r.nextInt(i2 + i1);
            rezr.setText("Rezultat: "+rez);
            rezr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    );
}
}
```

I'd like to mention that I used a samsung galaxy s6 edge+ to run the app and that I am new to Java/Android so if someone has a suggestion please explain it as simple as possible.
Thanks!

EDIT: The logcat doesn't return any error for me to search or to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this code will freeze after clicking a button, I think it will freeze just by opening the activity `intervalNumClass` because your code falls into an infinite loop at `onCreate()` !

look here:

```
do {
        itxt1.getText();
    }while(itxt1.length()<=0);
```

this is an infinite loop! you don't read input of `EditText` like this, but instead read it as follows:

```
i1=Integer.valueOf(itxt1.getText().toString());
```

And the other while loop as well will cause the same problem!

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't even notice, as I thought the problem was at the xml.

Comment: I got into another problem. The logcat returns "Invalid int: "" " do you have an idea how can I fix this? Is it true that this appears because I don't handle exceptions?

Comment: @RaresUrsu you have to use `try catch` because if use entered a non number text or empty text your app will crash with an exception like the one you got So you handle this by `try catch` block

Answer (score 0):

why you are using the while which doesn't make any sense here so remove both do while blocks which not needed here that will causing here recursion loop will not break as per your condition.

remove

```
do {
        itxt1.getText();
    }while(itxt1.length()<=0);

 do {
       itxt2.getText();
    }while(itxt2.length()<=0);
```